# diagonalizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ is $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb C$.
must exist that:

1. $A^*A$  is diagonalizable over C
2. $AA^*$ is unitary matrix
3. if $A$ is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$ so $AA^*$ is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$
4. $i+1$ is not eigenvalue of $A$

I know the answer is 1+4 but I really dont understand why!

- sorry for bad english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It's true, as any Hermitian matrix is diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$.
2. It's not necessarily true, for example if $A=2I$, $AA^*=4I$ is not unitary.
3. $AA^*$ is always diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$ (as a Hermitian matrix), independently of the fact that $A$ is diagonalizable or not.
4. May happen ($A=I$ for example) or not (if $A=(1+i)I$).

Comment: but in 1 how do I know A is Hermitian??

Comment: $A$ may be not Hermitian, but $A^*A$ is Hermitian (it follows from properties of the adjoint).